# scalar-converting copy constructor for class with type dependent constructor arguments

Tags: drake

### Situation

I realized that I've been writing a lot of `LeafSystem` classes that do very lightweight manipulation the input data and spits it out as output data.  They are all state-less and their only difference is the conversion function.

An example of this is a class which simply re-orders the input data or a class that simply strips away irrelevant input data.

Hence, I thought to write a `LeafSystem` class which takes this "conversion function" as argument to skip the headache of having to create a brand new class each time I want to process the input data in a slightly different way.

The idea is a constructor that takes a `std::function` of the form, along with input and output vector size.

```
std::function<void(const Eigen::VectorBlock<const drake::VectorX<T>>&, Eigen::VectorBlock<drake::VectorX<T>>& )>;
```

The "conversion function" can be implemented in this functor.

An example usecase would be if I wanted to convert a 3D state data (x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw) into 2D state data (x, y, yaw), I could just write a functor such as

```
void 3Dto2D(const Eigen::VectorBlock<const drake::VectorX<T>>& input, Eigen::VectorBlock<drake::VectorX<T>>& output)
{
    output[0] = input[0]; //x
    output[1] = input[1]; //y
    output[2] = input[5]; //yaw
    output[3] = input[6]; //x_dot
    output[4] = input[7]; //y_dot
    output[5] = input[11]; //yaw_dot
}
```

And pass this functor into this "StateConverter".

### Problem

The issue I'm facing is regarding the scalar-converting copy constructor.  How do I implement it when the class has type specific member objects?

#### The main body of this class is as follows (for completeness)

```
using ConversionFunc = std::function<void(const Eigen::VectorBlock<const drake::VectorX<T>>&, Eigen::VectorBlock<drake::VectorX<T>>& )>;;

// Some black magic to handle alias explicit template instantiation

template <typename T>
StateConverter<T>::StateConverter(ConversionFunc func, const unsigned int input_size, const unsigned int output_size) :
    systems::LeafSystem<T>(systems::SystemTypeTag<StateConverter>{}),
    input_idx(this->DeclareVectorInputPort("input_port", systems::BasicVector<T>(input_size)).get_index()),
    output_idx(this->DeclareVectorOutputPort("output_port", systems::BasicVector<T>(output_size), &StateConverter::convert).get_index())
{
    convert_func = func;
}

template <typename T>
void StateConverter<T>::convert(const drake::systems::Context<T>& context, systems::BasicVector<T>* output) const
{
    const auto state = this->EvalVectorInput(context, input_idx)->get_value();
    auto mutable_output = output->get_mutable_value();
    convert_func(state, mutable_output);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Partial Solution

I ended up creating a struct that holds all 3 required instances of the templated function

```
struct ConversionFunc
{
    std::function<void(const Eigen::VectorBlock<const drake::VectorX<double>>&, Eigen::VectorBlock<drake::VectorX<double>>& )> double_impl;
    std::function<void(const Eigen::VectorBlock<const drake::VectorX<drake::AutoDiffXd>>&, Eigen::VectorBlock<drake::VectorX<drake::AutoDiffXd>>& )> autodiff_impl;
    std::function<void(const Eigen::VectorBlock<const drake::VectorX<drake::symbolic::Expression>>&, Eigen::VectorBlock<drake::VectorX<drake::symbolic::Expression>>& )> symbolic_impl;
};
```

Which is what gets passed in the copy constructor

I create the struct as follows

```
template <typename T>
void convert_func(const Eigen::VectorBlock<const VectorX<T>>& state, Eigen::VectorBlock<VectorX<T>>& output)
{
    // Some example conversions
    output[0] = state[4];
    output[1] = state[6];
    output[2] = state[12];
    output[3] = state[14];
}

// I'm sure there's some way to automatically create these instantiations in the constructor of ConversionFunc...
ConversionFunc func;
func.double_impl = convert_func<double>;
func.autodiff_impl = convert_func<drake::AutoDiffXd>;
func.symbolic_impl = convert_func<drake::symbolic::Expression>;
```

And pass it to my `Converter` as follows

```
auto converter = builder.AddSystem(std::make_unique<StateConverter<double>>(func, 16, 4));
```

### Problem

Unfortunately, this method seems to be leaking memory causing `std::bad_alloc` to be thrown...